# Corrected standars deviation for confidence intervals

Tags: standard-deviation, t-confidence-interval

I have a multilinear regression model with 4 parameters and 164 observations. I want to determine the confidence intervals for each coefficient of the multilinear regression. I have the covariance matrix for the 4 parameters. The formula for calculating the confidence intervals for βᵢ, the coefficient corresponding to parameter xᵢ, is given by:

$IC = [βᵢ ± t_{α/2}^{n-p-1}  \sqrt{Var(βᵢ)/(n-p)}]$

Here, n represents the number of observations (164 in my case), p represents the number of parameters (4 in my case). $Var(βᵢ)$ refers to the corresponding element of the covariance matrix.

My question is should I divide by the (n-p) in the $\sqrt{Var(βᵢ)/(n-p)}$ or not, i find different versions of it on the internet.

Comment: It depends, because "$Var(\beta_i)$" is either zero or undefined (because $\beta_i$ is not a random variable: it's a parameter in the model).  Some formulas will refer to the *residual* variance, others to the *error* variance, and yet others to the *sampling variance* of the *estimate* of $\beta_i.$  Could you please tell us, then, exactly how you interpret "$Var(\beta_i)$"?

Comment: The thing I don't know exactly how they are calculated, all I know that model is a multilinear regression and in the output i have the covariance matrix with correlations of variables and their standard deviations, so I assume it's a classic covariance matrix that normally is calculated in a multilinear regression model as: $\hat{\Gamma}_n=\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^n\left(X_k-\bar{X}_n\right)^t\left(X_k-\bar{X}_n\right) .$

Comment: Please visit the results of this site search for [multiple regression variance matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multiple+regression+variance+matrix).